# How to use IN clause in JPA?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA to get the result from table with in clause but facing below exception:

```
ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Fail to convert to internal representation
```

PFB my code:

```
public interface ObjectCommonDao extends JpaRepository<ObjectCommon, Long> {

    @Query("select oc from ObjectCommon oc where oc.id in :listObjects")
    List<ObjectCommon> getListSelectedObject(@Param("listObjects") List<Long> listSelected);

}
```

Could you please let me know how to use IN clause in above query to get list of rows.

Comment: Is 'id' field of ObjectCommon defined as Long?

Comment: Post the entity, and the complete stack trace of the exception

Comment: Yes. Id field is long.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
select oc from ObjectCommon oc where oc.id in (:listObjects)
```